# Not seeing results with Telerik's Persistence Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, persistence

As I understand things, from following guides over at Telerik, what I have below should be enough to persist the state of the RadTreeView in my user control. But it doesn't.

In the MainPage.aspx:

```
<telerik:RadPersistenceManager ID="RadPersistenceManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadPersistenceManager>
```

In the .aspx of the user control:

```
​<telerik:RadPersistenceManagerProxy ID="RadPersistenceManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <PersistenceSettings>
        <telerik:PersistenceSetting ControlID="RadTreeView1" />
    </PersistenceSettings>
</telerik:RadPersistenceManagerProxy>
```

In the user control's code behind:

```
private RadPersistenceManager _persistenceManager;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            _persistenceManager = RadPersistenceManager.GetCurrent(Page);
            if (!IsPostBack)
                _persistenceManager.LoadState();
        }


protected void RadTreeView1_NodeCheck(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
        {           

            _persistenceManager.SaveState();
        }
```

(I have also tried calling LoadState() and SaveState() on the main page instead (in page_load on non-postbacks, and in pre_render on postbacks, respectively).

But in neither case the control's state persists across states.

What needs to be done for it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start from this demo and modify it to match your setup: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/applicationscenarios/persisting-treeview-settings/defaultcs.aspx?product=persistenceframework.

Also, if you are using load-on-demand for the treeview, this won't work. In this case the items are not loaded when you attempt to save/load their state.